# Kotlin abstract generic with ProGuard

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I have the following base class:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T : BaseViewModel> : Fragment(), JobHolder {
    protected lateinit var viewModel: T
        private set

    protected fun provideViewModel(type: Class<T>) {
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(type)
    }
}
```

and the following class:

```
class SubjectEditor : BaseFragment<SubjectEditorViewModel>() {
    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        provideViewModel(SubjectEditorViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

But ProGuard is complaining:

```
Warning: cz.x.ui.subjects.SubjectEditor: can't find referenced method 'void setViewModel(cz.x.ui.BaseViewModel)' in program class cz.x.ui.subjects.SubjectEditor
```

I tried some `-keep` rules for ProGuard, but nothing worked. What's the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want it not to be obfuscated, so in that case you should keep the methods in the abstract class:

```
-keep public class {path to your class}.BaseFragment{
   private <methods>;
}
```

There's a really usefull ProguardGuide in [this link](https://jebware.com/blog/?p=418)
After reading it you should be more confident on which rules you should use.

I hope it helps, otherwise let me know!

Comment: That's not it. Even when I do `-keep class cz.x.ui.BaseFragment { *; }`, I get the warnings.